# the previous html when using .load() method in jQuery

Tags: jquery

when loading part of a document into  jquery using the

method

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

I am trying to understand if there is a simple solution to produce

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/previouspage.html #container" );
```

I understand that jQuery simply returns the element and its contents into the element with an ID of #result

I have lots of pages on a single website that contain a form which prefills another contact form located on pagexyz.html

My question: Is there a simple way of replacing the "ajax/test.hml" with page1.html or page2.html or page3.html...

whatever the previous page was in order to insert that page's content into pagexyz.html

How can I represent the ( "previouspage.html  in a way the will work?

Comment: You're looking for the wonders of string concatenation.

Comment: I realize now that it can be replaced with either ServerSide Includes Command echo var HTTP_REFERER  or with php HTTP_REFERER echo $ref -------  Will this work in all cases? I have read that sometimes the REFERER method does NOT always work. I have tested it and cannot find any issues

Comment: Some browsers do not send the Referer header.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using $(this).("page2.html");

but this will refresh the entire page, and page2.html will be the only one displaying on screen.

Comment: I am attempting to load an element from a previously visited .html